# Deploy and configure program on users PC through Group Policy

Tags: active-directory, backup, group-policy

Sorry if this is a noob question but basically I am looking to put a program "Veeam Endpoint Backup" onto all of the users PC using Active Directory Group Policy instead of going through every PC to add a backup job to the program.

Is there a way to get the backup job to all of the PC's? (the configuration would all be the same, backup system `C:` to a shared folder on the network)

In general I guess I would like to know if your able to configure software through active directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot deploy software package using active directory(AD). We can deploy any application using GPOs.
These links might help you:
 - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/816102

- https://www.clarosoftware.com/help/how-to-use-group-policy-to-remotely-install-software-in-windows-server-2012/

Other way is to deploy a custom image using Windows deployment services.

Comment: Thank you so much Karan for the response! I guess im out of luck then but at least I know its not possible now instead of wasting time looking more into it. I will give this question 24 hours for others to respond and if no one responds in that time frame saying otherwise then I will accept your answer as the approved answer. Thank you again! :)

Comment: I just wanted to add a comment here saying that a lot of programs are able to be ran from the command line. So you are able to kick off the backup job (or desired task) via windows task scheduler or cron job depending on the operating system your using. and any files that need to be put onto the PC's (e.g. backup job file or configuration file) through a group policy object in active directory, or even using powershell to put files to multiple pc's with one command. Hopefully this  will help others. If the program cant run via command line then you may have to look for another way.